# CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka for my project development. I am using a topic which have :

partitions : 5

min.insync.replicas: 3

I am calling few rest end points inside the "@KakfaListener" and whatever response i am getting from those rest end points that i am publishing to two different topic.

For rest end points its taking around 20-25 seconds and for publishing to two different topic is taking around 15 seconds.

On an average  we are completing all rest end point call and Kafka publisher call in 35-40 seconds, which i believe less the max poll interval  time. But after processing around 100 records, i am getting following exception:

> CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms

Following I have given consumer property:

```
props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
props.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
props.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offsetReset);
props.put(ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, Boolean.FALSE);
props.put(MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 50);
props.put(SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
props.put(MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 300000);
```

and following is the listener:

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "${test.topic}")
public void consume(
      @NotNull final ConsumerRecord<String, String> cr,
      @Payload final String payload,
      final Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

    final XYZObject xyzObject =
        objectMapper.readValue(payload, XYZObject.class);

    log.info("Name =\"{}\"", xyzObject.getName());
    final Instant prcTime = Instant.now();
    final Response response = processPayload(xyzObject);
    log.info(
        "processPayload() took =\"{}\"ms", Duration.between(prcTime, Instant.now()).toMillis());

    final Instant pblshTime = Instant.now();
    publishResponseToKafka(response, xyzObject);
    log.info(
            "publishResponseToKafka() took =\"{}\"ms", Duration.between(pblshTime, Instant.now()).toMillis());
    try {
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    } catch(CommitFailedException  ce){
      log.error("commitFailedException: {}", ce);
    }
}
```

Comment: 40*100 = 4000 seconds

The default `max.poll.interval.ms` is 5 minutes (300 seconds).

You need to reduce `max.poll.records` or increase `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: Thank you @Gary Russell. Actually I am processing around 22000 records. As per your suggestion, following are the consumer configs:

        props.put(MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 25);
        props.put(SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
        props.put(MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 600000);

Still its giving  commitFailedException.

Comment: And how long does it take to process those 25 records? You won't get that failure unless the processing exceeds the `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: @GaryRussell , it will take around 750 ms to process all these 25 records.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be seeing a rebalance; look in the server logs. What versions are you using? (broker, kafka-clients, spring-kafka)?

Comment: As Gary says, you will only get that error message when you take longer than max.poll.interval.ms between successive calls to poll. As you are using KafkaListener, the poll calls are being done by spring-kafka so the only explanation is that you are taking longer than 5 minutes to process a batch. Keep your config simple, don't mess with session timeout - that is not your problem. Let's look at what you are doing when processing each message....

Comment: So you have acks=all? With 3 insync replicas then any lag between brokers would delay publishing - that's one possibility. Why not strip things back and add them in bit by bit

Comment: Sorry, that meant to say DO you have acks=all !

Comment: I see you have timings there but one slow batch will cause a rebalance even if those are your normal timings. Is failure to commit consistently after 100 ie one batch okay, second batch fails to complete? After rebalance is it 100 again? Is there a pattern or is it just occasional?

Comment: Regarding acks=all that does rather depend how you are sending, as the publish and wait for acks is in a separate thread, unless you wait for response in your sending thread.

Comment: @GaryRussell, Thanks for your valuable suggestions. I had added changes , recommended by you. I have increased the timeout a lil more and now, it working perfectly.